# Adding an active class on ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 buttons and I just want to add a class when the button has been clicked.

```
       <button class="panel-btn" 
        ui-sref="basechat" 
        ng-click="setBaseChat()" id="base-chat-btn">Base Chat</button>
        <button class="panel-btn" 
        ui-sref="banner" 
        ng-click="setBannerChat()" 
        id="banner-chat-btn">Banner</button>
```

The function on `ng-click` returns a `true` value.

Hope you guys can help me, I still don't understand very well how `ng-class` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a class to a button on click you can do something like this:

```
<button ng-class="{someClass: someTruthyValue}" ng-click="someFunction()">
```

The `ng-class` will look at the value of `someTruthyValue` and display `someClass` if it is True, and not otherwise.

For example, your JS could look something like:

```
$scope.someTruthyValue = False;

$scope.someFunction = function() {
    $scope.someTruthyValue = True;
}
```

The [docs are fairly good](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#example) here

Also, as you can see in the other answers, there is more than 1 way to use `ng-class`, however I like my solution because it allows you the option to link additional button to *reverse* the class change:

```
<button ng-click="someReverseFunction()">
```

Where, certainly:

```
$scope.someReverseFunction = function() {
    $scope.someTruthyValue = False;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this gave me a nice view of how it works and how I can inprove my code!

Answer (score 2):

As a simple example, you could have:

```
$scope.bannerClass = "baseClass"; // baseClass defined in your CSS

$scope.setBannerChat = function() {
    $scope.bannerClass = "myClass"; // myClass defined in your CSS
    // or $scope.bannerClass = "baseClass myClass";
}
```

and then:

```
<div ng-class="bannerClass">Hello</div>
<button ng-click=setBannerChat()></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your controller:

```
 $scope.clickFucntion = function(){
     $scope.myClass = 'my-class';
 }
```

and this in your view:

```
 <button class="{{myClass}}" ng-click="clickFucntion()">
```